# Is it acceptable to implement abbreviated elements and will users know what they mean?

Tags: icons

More websites are including icons and visual elements over text allowing for more space and cleaner design. Elements like social icons (FB, Twitter), views, likes, favorite, comments, etc don't require text as users know what they do and mean. I'd like to implement an abbreviated element showing when content was added, but I'd like to know if the general population of users will know what this means.

Will users understand this means X days ago and is this an accepted means of showing time? This will change according to the time, i.e W (week), M (month), Y (year).

[image]

Comment: I find uppercase `D` for days a bit confusing, especially in the combination `3D`.

Comment: How about using ３日? Clear and unambiguous :P

Answer (score 3):

**[Accessbility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) matters.**

On the Web, you have tools, use them :

- The `abbr` element, for abbreviations. Very handy.
- The `title` attribute, for descriptions. It shows a tooltip on graphic Web browsers.
- The `alt` attribute for images. It is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically three conditions in which an abbreviation will be understood:

1. The abbreviation is already a standard use
2. There is only one, common term the abbreviated form could resolve to.
3. There is sufficient context or accompanying iconography for users to guess the meaning of the cypher.

Users will probably understand the example you've given because it satisfies all three of these cases.

That being said, the number of users who understand the abbreviation will always be less than the number who understand the full version. I can't tell you how many (that may be domain and audience specific), but I would ask whether this is really necessary. Is the potential loss of clarity really worth the three extra characters?

Comment: On the Web, don't expect all users to see the iconography. Hence the usefulness of the — mandatory — `alt` attribute.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - in non-visual media, there isn't need to abbreviate for compactness reasons anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal answer to this question.  What *your* users will understand may be very different from what *my* users understand.  You really have to make informed choices and then test them with your user base.

That said, there are a few abbreviations that are almost universal:
 - **Months** of the year: Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.
 - **Days** of the week: Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.
 - **Time**: hr, min, sec (and in context, d, h, m, s)

Whatever you do, **you need to test it with your users**.

Comment: I'm sure this doesn't apply to the OP, but I'm really concerned that these sorts of questions around "universal behaviours" _might_ belie a tendency to rely on the "insights" of a UX field that's still young and highly contested over real-world validation.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye I think the UX insights help you make a better first guess, but that doesn't at all take away from the need for real-world validation.

Comment: The abbreviation *min* is standard and well understood. But your abbreviations *hr* and *sec* are far from universal, they are wrong. The correct abbreviations are *h*, *min*, *s*.

Answer (score 1):

As CodesInChaos mentioned 3D is so ubiquitous in another context that it is not the right choice because automatic associations have to be overridden.

The caps choice also is problematic: "3D AGO" looks like a weird year, or other code.

There is another tension in your design as the icon does not correspond directly to your concept: clocks represent minutes and hours, not days. (They do signal the passage of time as a general concept though so I understand the initial choice).

I would use a calendar icon and the text "3 days ago" (arranged serially or text within icon if space is a major constraint).